# Visual Studio 2008 format settings

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I know in the tools-> options menu you can change the format settings for C# text editor.  You can change the spacing and bracket formatting.

### Question

Is there a way to configure the settings to enforce variable and method naming conventions such as pascal-case (MyVariable) and camel-case(myVariable)?  If so, is there also a way to enforce a rule like hungarian case (lAccountNum where l is saying it is a long integer) is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/).